# Algorithm design for a js loop structure

Tags: javascript

I got an array `[1,2,3,4]`

I need first to run over [2] that was chosen, set his styles, **and than after** run over the other children and reset their styles.

At the moment, **my algorithm** is as following:

```
for item in array
    if item == chosenEl
        set chosen classes
for item in array
    if item != chosenEl
        reset chosen classes for the rest of the children
```

Or **coffe**:

```
for item in @array
    if item.element is element
        item.selected = true
        item.element.classList.add @selectedClass
        item.element.focus()
for item in @array
    if item.element isnt element
        item.selected = false
        item.element.classList.remove @selectedClass
```

I need to design the function like that, and not as a simple forElse loop, due to some restrictions in me framework.

How can I improve this code?

Thank you.

**Explanation**- The reason I need this design, is due to duplicated calls for 2 different functions, that conflict one the other.

I'm developing an app for LG TV. The LG TV has its own libraries. Now in my function I set the styles of chosen elements. Byt when I focus to the chosen element, I activate the LG TV onFocus listener, which in his turn control the selected styles.

So when I loop the second or third child, I set again the selected styles, of cleared elements. TLDR but thats how the loops conflicting each other. One interrupting the work of other.

The code was not written by me. I entered an existing project, and I havent written this function, so i cannot just remove the Focus() function.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping twice, consider below code

```
for item in array
{
    if item == chosenEl
    {
        set chosen classes
        continue; <--use this to return to next iteration without executing next statements
    } 
   reset chosen classes for the rest of the children
}
```

It will be O(n) instead of O(n) + O(n)

**Edit:**

I am sorry, I didn't understand your explanation. If all you need is a function which you can repeatedly call then here it is, call resetStyles multiple times by passing selected value. Please note since you haven't provided exact data types, I assumed them as integers.

```
<script>
var resetStyles = function(selecteditem)
{
   var arr = [1,2,3,4];
   for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
   {
      if(arr[i] == selecteditem)
      {
        //set class here

        continue;
      }
      //remove class here
   }
};
resetStyles(2);//call this by changing the values
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Sundeep. Thank you for your comment, but as I explained in the OP, I cannot run a simple ForElse due to restrictions of my FW. I will explain upstairs what is my restriction, that demanded me to think about this design.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you looping twice? Far easier to just do:

```
for( var i=0, l=array.length; i<l; i++) {
    if( item == chosenEl) {
        // set styles
    }
    else {
        // clear styles
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kolink. Thank you for your comment, but as I explained in the OP, I cannot run a simple ForElse due to restrictions of my FW.  I will explain upstairs what is my restriction, that demanded me to think about this design.